# CSS HTML make div scroll to height of content

Tags: html, css, scroll, position

I have a fixed nav bar running the length of my website, but just now it currently has it's own scrollbar, so when i scroll on the body of the website, the navbar is static, and will only scroll if i physically scroll over the navbar itself.

Is this just the outcome of 'position: fixed;' or am i missing something in my CSS?

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #555;
    font: normal 1.3em Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    background-color: #FAFAF0;
    font-family: "proxima-nova",sans-serif;
    display: block;
}
/*NAVBAR*/
    #sidebar-wrapper {
        position: fixed;
        background: #2C4649;
        z-index: 1000;
        left: 0px;
        height: 100%;
        margin-left: 0px;
        border: none;
        display: block;
        -moz-border-radius: 0;
        -o-border-radius: 0;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0;
        border-radius: 0;
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }
/*PAGE CONTENT TO THE RIGHT OF NAVBAR*/
#page-content-wrapper {
    margin-top: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 130px;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this so the full height of the website is dependant on either the navbar content or page content - rather than being separate scrollable items?

Thanks

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle/code snippet/codepen?

Comment: Fixed position elements are fixed with respect to the viewport, so scrolling the window's scrollbar won't affect it.

Comment: Here's a jsFiddle of my content https://jsfiddle.net/krzuz842/1/ 

The Navbar has an independent scroll to he body, i want to be able to scroll on the body and get to see the full navbar, if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're after, but here's an example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7p341k1o/).

All I did was this rule: `#sidebar-wrapper{overflow-y:hidden;}` which will remove any scrollbar in the fixed element. This means that if there is too much content in the navbar, it will be **cut off and not visisble** (hence "hidden"). If you are already experiencing a scrollbar in the fixed nav bar, it means you have too much content in it, so this might not be the best solution for you.

Then I added a fixed width of the sidebar to match the margin offset of your content.